# Is there any way of automatically find all third-party components used on a project?

Tags: delphi

Is there any Delphi expert or similar that allows me to automatically find all third-party components used on a project?

I need to send a project that uses several third-party components and in order to compile I'll also have to include the third-party components it uses. Any quicker way than manually looking at all the forms for third-party components?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Clear out the Delphi search paths in the global and project options and re-add them one-by-one when the compiler or IDE complains.  You may need to delete your DCUs.

Another source-based approach you could use is to run [XN Resource Editor](http://www.wilsonc.demon.co.uk/d10resourceeditor.htm) on your executable, and look at the `RC Data\PACKAGEINFO\Language Neutral` node.  The **Contains** tab will show every unit that's linked into your executable.

Comment: I was hoping there would be a tool that could do this automatically but doesn't seem like the case right?

Answer (score 3):

Borland had a tool a few years ago now called "VCLScanner".  It parsed all your source and told you what components you used and in how many places.  It sounds just like what you are asking for. This is a link to it: http://www.torry.net/pages.php?id=482

Comment: It looks like this just scans the DFM data, so it won't detect components created at runtime, and it won't show components that you've inherited from (e.g., our controls all descend from the TNT ones, but TNT itself doesn't get listed).