# How to automatically list all third-party components used in a java + React project?

Tags: java, reactjs, components, open-source

For legal reasons we are required to provide a list of all open-source components used in our project. It is a commercial java + React project using Gradle, npm and Yarn.

In this context, do you know of any tool or automatic way to extract the list of distributed third-parties used in the java and/or javascript code base?
As it is a pretty large code base it would be quite impractical to do it by hand...

My best attempts so far are [jdeps](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/jdeps.htm) for the java code, and `yarn list` for the javascript part... but they do not really do what I want.

Searching S.O. I found [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080186/is-there-any-way-of-automatically-find-all-third-party-components-used-on-a-proj) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41719562/how-to-list-all-open-source-components-used-in-a-rails-application), but on other languages. I am not quite sure this is the right place to ask, but it seems to me that other people could face the same issue...

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most likely have to configure the license check in the build tools that you are using:

- Gradle has [License Gradle Plugin](https://github.com/hierynomus/license-gradle-plugin)
- NPM has [license-checker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/license-checker) or few other tools
- Yarn has [licenses](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/licenses/)